# What is a stopped process in linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, php

So I had some PHP scripts running from the command line, and wanted to stop them running.

I ran

```
$ ps aux | grep php
$ sudo kill 8754
$ sudo kill 8767
```

And then ran

```
$ ps aux | grep php
```

again to check the processes had terminated but got this kind of output:

```
jon      8754  0.4 53.5 3044256 2205204 ?     T    10:34   0:15 php awesome_script.php
jon      8767  0.4 53.5 3044256 2205204 ?     T    10:34   0:15 php awesome_script.php
jon     12275  0.0  0.0   4156   892 pts/1    S+   11:27   0:00 grep --color=auto php
```

I [looked up what the T meant](http://slack-linux.blogspot.co.uk/2009/07/linux-process-state-codes.html) in the state column and discovered that it means Stopped, but I don't understand what that means the process is doing.

I know you can [create your own signal handling](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php) in PHP, but I've not done that, so when PHP receives a [SIGTERM signal](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-signals-traps.htm) what does it do?

What is a stopped process doing (if anything)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It means the process has received a `STOP` signal, and won't do anything much until it receives a `CONT` signal, not even terminate.

The most common source of `STOP` signals is the user hitting `^z` while the process is in the foreground, and the common way to send a `CONT` afterwards is typing `fg` or `bg` which continue the process in the foreground and background respectively.

Another way to send `STOP` to a process is `kill -STOP $pid`. Similarly, `CONT` can be sent to a process with `kill -CONT $pid`.

Since you sent `TERM` signals to the processes, I assume you want them to terminate. For that to happen, the processes must receive `CONT` signals. You can send those by typing `kill -CONT 8754 8767` in a terminal window.

Comment: Would sending a CONT signal allow the script to run until it had completed? Or would it cause the script to terminate immediately?

Comment: The process continues what it was doing (before STOP) upon receiving a CONT. If you sent a TERM (by `kill $pid` for example) while it was stopped, however, it will then (belatedly) respond to that TERM and terminate.

Comment: Hmm, so I sent a TERM by running `kill 8754` which should cause the process to eventually terminate right? Do you know which state a process would be in while it's getting round to terminating? Given that the process entered the STOP state, as if it had received a STOP signal from `kill -STOP 8754`, could that also happen if it was sent a TERM signal?

Comment: A stopped process will not terminate due to a `TERM` signal until it is continued. It will terminate immediately if it receives a `KILL` signal, even while stopped. I assume a process will be in Run state when it terminates. I'm not very familiar with PHP, and don't know how to tell why a process stopped, sorry. Generally, though, processes don't stop but terminate when they receive `TERM`.

Answer (score 4):

The stopped process in Linux/Unix is a process/task which received suspend signal (`SIGSTOP`/`SIGTSTP`) which tells kernel to not perform any processing on it as it has been stopped, and it can only be resume its execution if it is sent the `SIGCONT` signal.

Basically stopped process awaits a continuation signal from the kernel, similarly as suspended process awaits a wake-up condition from the kernel.

[image: Linux kernel process states: Ready, Running, Stopped, Suspended, Traced, Zombie]

<sup>Image credits: [polytechnique.fr](https://www.enseignement.polytechnique.fr/informatique/INF422/INF422_6.pdf)</sup>

---

Each process in Linux kernel is represented by a `task_struct` data structure and each `task` vector consist array of pointers to every `task_struct`. which describes a process or task in the system (either it's `unrunnable`, `runnable` or `stopped`). See: [Processes](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/kernel/processes.html) and [Linux Data Structures](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/ds/ds.html)) for more details.

See also: [The Linux Kernel: Process Management](http://cs-pub.bu.edu/fac/richwest/cs591_w1/notes/linux_process_mgt.PDF)

Comment: @Jus Thanks for report, I've corrected it.