# Differences between STOPPED in top command and STOPPED in ps

Tags: linux, command-line, docker, top, ps

I have a running script in a docker container. After a while, I found that the processes seemed to be in stuck when I used `ps -ef` command, since the TIME field for those processes were stuck in a constant time like `00:00:05`. I think from `ps`, those processes were still running(?). But from `top` command, I could clearly see that those processes were with `T` state which means they were stopped. So what's the difference between these two commands? Why `ps` showing those processes still running? How can I resume those processes?

Comment: Does [command line - What is a stopped process in linux? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/403200/what-is-a-stopped-process-in-linux?rq=1) answer your question?